# cannot install PCManFM version 1.2.0

Tags: software-installation, pcmanfm

I have Lubuntu 13.10. I am trying to install PCManFM 1.2.0.  I go to the prompt, use `cd` command to go to my downloads directory and type `./configure` to start the process of installing it. Errors I am getting reads as follows:

```
checking for msgmerge... /usr/bin/msgmerge
checking for msgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for gmsgfmt... /usr/bin/msgfmt
checking for perl... /usr/bin/perl
checking for perl >= 5.8.1... 5.14.2
checking for XML::Parser... ok
checking for pkg-config... /usr/bin/pkg-config
checking pkg-config is at least version 0.9.0... yes
checking for XLIB... no
configure: error: Package requirements ("x11") were not met:

No package 'x11' found

Consider adjusting the PKG_CONFIG_PATH environment variable if you
installed software in a non-standard prefix.

Alternatively, you may set the environment variables XLIB_CFLAGS
and XLIB_LIBS to avoid the need to call pkg-config.

See the pkg-config man page for more details.
edwin@edwin-ThinkPad-R52:~/Downloads/pcmanfm-1.2.0$
```

I am just new to Lubuntu (was XP for years and years). What causes this and how can it be fixed so I can continue installing version 1.2.0 ?

Answer (score 2):

I don't believe that PCManFM 1.2.0 is available in the Lubuntu 13.10 repositories so you have to add it.

sudo apt-add-repository ppa:lubuntu-dev/lubuntu-daily
sudo apt-get update
sudo apt-get install pcmanfm

Of course you will be asked for your password.  Just enter it and enter.